# How can I make sure an init.d-script runs after network-interfaces received their addresses over DHCP?

Tags: debian, dhcp, init, couchdb, sysv

I just installed couchdb on a debian5 system and added symlinks to the /etc/init.d/couchdb-script. Unfortunately, this script gets triggered on startup before the network interface received the address over DHCP that the couchdb-server tries to bind to - which leaves the instance defunct.

I kind of solved this, by executing dhclient in the start script, but there just *HAS* to be a better way...? Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way: place your couchdb init script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` so it will run after your network is set up.

Pay attention to:

> ```
>    Filenames should consist entirely of upper and lower case
>    letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens. Subdirectories  
>    of directory and files with other names will be silently ignored.
> ```

Comment: I have a problem with if-up scripts being run before DHCP. All my services are starting up while there's no DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf! http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272459/84496

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS and probably RedHat it checks to see if there is a file `/sbin/ifup-local` and will execute that if it is available.

to create it:

```
sudo touch /sbin/ifup-local
sudo chmod +x /sbin/ifup-local
```

Then edit it to contain what you would like

```
#!/bin/sh
# your commands or calls to your script here
```

Hope that helps. I like Debian's `.d` directory better but this seems to be the closest equivalent on CentOS.